# Is it possible to change the size of the alt attribute of an image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I would like to show alt values when displaying images:

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
<li><img src="images/cpu.jpg" alt="Over All CPU" /></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#demo img { font:italic 100px Georgia, Times, Serif; color: #000; text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #222; margin:10px 20px; }
```

Is it possible to make the alt size big? If not, is there a way to put a title to the image when displaying?

Answer (score 0):

The alt property is a property of the image tag, it's not an element by itself. You can't style the alt property its same as src

but you can use the  [jQuery Tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) to get this effect

Comment: Hold your horses. I wouldn't be surprised if certain browsers *do* let you style their default tool-tips.

Comment: @imeVidas: Nah, there aren't ones that you can reliably do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload()  event handler or onmouseover() event handler to display the text on image in whichever style you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the alt size big?

Like said above, there is no way to style the alt. The alt attribute serves two purposes.

1. If the image fails to load or if the user has images off, it is
   shown.
2. The text in the alt is reported to assistive technology,
   such as JAWS, so users can get an equal experience.

> If not, is there a way to put a title to the image when displaying?

Can't you simply do:

```
<figure>
 <img src="" alt="Over All CPU">
 <figcaption>Your title goes here, which should not be Over All CPU</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[Ref](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/)